# load-grunt-config returning ReferenceError constantly

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm new to both node and grunt, however, I have followed this guide here (http://mattbailey.io/a-beginners-guide-to-grunt-redux.html) to setup my gruntfile and associated tasks in a modular way.

I'm having trouble when I try and run any grunt task as it just gives me a "ReferenceError: grunt is not defined" output and then tells me it cannot find the task.

Any suggestions would be amazing. I have tried searching but can't seem to find any answer that fixes the issue. :(

Comment: Please share your `package.json` file.

Comment: I started again from scratch and it worked... No config changed so no idea what this issue was. Thanks for replying though :)